# PCA plot on repeats grouped by condition

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, ggfortify

I'm trying to produce a PCA plot on expression data produced from 3 conditions with 3 repeats each. I've managed to get a plot but then am struggling to colour and group the conditions as I think I may have laid the data out wrong.

And then I've run the following code by am stuck when I get to colouring each sample. I want to colour by O, FO and F containing each of the 3 repeats and then ellipse these 3 conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

The table:

```
structure(list(Gene_ID = c("gene-EHS42_RS00005", "gene-EHS42_RS00010", 
"gene-EHS42_RS00015", "gene-EHS42_RS00020", "gene-EHS42_RS00025", 
"gene-EHS42_RS00030", "gene-EHS42_RS00035", "gene-EHS42_RS00040", 
"gene-EHS42_RS00045", "gene-EHS42_RS00050", "gene-EHS42_RS00055", 
"gene-EHS42_RS00060", "gene-EHS42_RS00065", "gene-EHS42_RS00070", 
"gene-EHS42_RS00075", "gene-EHS42_RS00080"), O1 = c(757.784, 
896.264, 123.429, 985.022, 85.8583, 111.718, 10.7002, 152.577, 
17.7682, 1086.55, 2826.57, 109.637, 43.1502, 0, 3158.45, 2271.19
), O2 = c(723, 897.502, 157.31, 1075.96, 106.999, 118.593, 10.8549, 
137.093, 19.2265, 1142.01, 2841.09, 91.1191, 63.1088, 0, 2981.31, 
2136.32), O3 = c(724.17, 875.258, 133.573, 1155.09, 74.4442, 
107.826, 16.365, 164.105, 29.4387, 751.156, 2822.42, 93.7586, 
37.7846, 0, 2978.32, 2045.64), FO1 = c(688.876, 922.35, 135.935, 
1223.9, 119.83, 93.1258, 17.7483, 324.379, 77.5033, 862.804, 
2524.59, 95.5171, 53.9344, 0, 2455.88, 1462.5), FO2 = c(869.985, 
1185.33, 194.729, 882.644, 177.953, 135.183, 21.7251, 296.909, 
58.101, 1247, 2511.67, 114.952, 63.6875, 0, 1433.23, 904.294), 
    FO3 = c(840.392, 1195.88, 165.721, 937.342, 170.775, 145.854, 
    23.9473, 285.05, 44.2553, 1402.51, 2737.45, 100.696, 73.0917, 
    0, 1419.96, 1051.12), F1 = c(1718.91, 1729.51, 341.759, 1324.52, 
    86.4022, 264.029, 30.6917, 169.219, 37.1905, 1987.85, 1370.75, 
    97.2895, 69.3806, 0, 3641.66, 2916.67), F2 = c(1919.41, 1666.16, 
    323.399, 850.732, 67.4236, 271.421, 18.9667, 184.824, 18.0931, 
    1617.57, 1449.76, 86.3241, 48.5885, 0, 2524.14, 1730.51), 
    F3 = c(1951.07, 1850.52, 376.333, 1157.23, 41.8972, 277.754, 
    32.3741, 177.472, 34.1986, 1039.71, 874.081, 78.1316, 58.6108, 
    0, 3424.35, 2758.01)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

And then the code I ran:

```
str(PcA_Plot_Data)
head(PcA_Plot_Data)

expression.pca <- prcomp(PcA_Plot_Data[,c(2:10)],
                         centre = TRUE,
                         scale. = TRUE)
summary(expression.pca)

library(ggfortify)
expression.pca.plot <- autoplot(expression.pca,
                                data = PcA_Plot_Data,
                                colour = '')
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your data. I'm a little confused though. The point of PCA is to abstract away your existing variables into principal components. Each point on a PCA plot will be based on the weightings from all three of the variables O, FO and F, so I don't know what you mean about colouring by O, FO and F? Similarly, drawing ellipses only works with grouping variables, not the variables you are using to create the PCA. You could color by Gene perhaps? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Sorry I'm a biologist not a programmer so not 100% sure what I am doing. I basically have three different test conditions (O, FO and F) which each have 3 replicates (1,2 and 3). There's gene expression values for each of these replicates which I need to plot a PCA graph for testing for condition, not replicate. So they want me to colour code by condition (i.e. a colour for O, FO and F, not for replicate number 1, 2 and 3).

Comment: I'm not a programmer either, but I have some knowledge of R, and of PCA. It would just about make sense to carry out a PCA using three columns (one for each condition), because the resulting principal components would show something useful, but then you would have to group by replicate or by Gene, since the conditions have been converted to principal components. This is evidently not what you want. But then if you want something that can be colored according to condition, you would have to use the three replicates as columns. I find this problematic, because then ->

Comment: the principal components are made up of different variables altogether, and don't have any physical meaning. Yes, the plot would be grouped by condition and could have ellipses etc, but the principal components would be completely meaningless, and it's not at all clear what the plot would show. I just don't think your data lends itself to PCA grouped by condition, and I'm puzzled about what you are being asked to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that it is convention that genes should rows and columns should be samples. But you're running the PCA on untransposed data, but I assume you want to have each sample as a single dot in te final plot. Here is the minimal version on what to do.

**Note** that I am not checking whether your data needs normalization or any transformation such as log, it just demonstrates how to do PCA based on such data. It's on you to check how to make them appropriate for such analysis:

```r
# It's kind of convention to have gene expression data as numeric matrix/data.frame without genes as a column
data <- as.data.frame(data)
rownames(data) <- data$Gene_ID
data$Gene_ID <- NULL

# Run PCA on transposed data
pca <- prcomp(t(data))

# Parse group names
groups <- gsub("1|2|3", "", colnames(data))

# Biplot
library(ggplot2)
to_plot <- data.frame(pca$x, group=groups)

ggplot(data=to_plot, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=group)) + geom_point(size=3)
```

[image]